# upgrading solution with many projects asp.net from 4.6 to 6.0

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, sdk, microservices, upgrade

I try to use upgrade-assistant but it didn't work in a solution with many projects , the projects version didn't upgraded to version 6.0, and try-covert also didn't work

How to solve this issue

Comment: Provide logs please or write better description "what going wrong" ?

Comment: Hello @hamaronooo , the versions of the project is still 4.6.2 and didn't upgraded to 6.0.

Answer (score 0):

### Migrate Web Site

To upgrade from **asp.net forms** to net 6  - is impossible - you must rewrite everything, including the libraries.

The way **asp.net forms** works it totally different than net 6.

To move from **asp.net MVC** project to net 6, its again a page by page conversion. You have the choice to do that incremental using the [YARP proxy](https://microsoft.github.io/reverse-proxy/) a tool by microsoft.

a step by step tutorial and video can be found here:
[Incremental ASP.NET to ASP.NET Core Migration](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/incremental-asp-net-to-asp-net-core-migration/)

### Migrate Libraries

The libraries can migrate if you are not use part of asp.net forms, like the

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
```

You can create a new project for net 6, and there link the files of the old project (not copy, but [link them](https://jeremybytes.blogspot.com/2019/07/linking-files-in-visual-studio.html)) and step by step migrate them to net 6. You can do the same and for all the tests.

After that you use  [C# preprocessor directives](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives) to fix small different - eg:

```
#if NETFRAMEWORK 
    
#elif NET || NETSTANDARD

#endif
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort , but you can explain more since the issue is not clear yet

Comment: @HassanShreim Do you use `asp.net forms` ?